# AfterEffects Script - Create Excel data using script

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

nice to meet you!
I'm currently making an AfterEffect script that writes layer information to Excel, but no matter how much I research, I can't find a way to do it. If someone knows how to do it, can you tell me?

Actually, I'm Japanese and I don't understand English very well, so I used Google Translate to write the sentences, so I'm glad if it's conveyed well.

Answer (score 0):

Layer information can be obtained from the API using the [Layer object](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/layers/layer.html) which can be accessed directly like so: `app.project.item(index).layer(index)` or by looping through a [CompItem](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/items/compitem.html)'s layers like so:

```
var theComp = app.project.activeItem;
for (var i = 1; i <= theComp.numLayers; i++){
    // layers in a comp are indexed from 1, rather than 0
    theLayer = theComp.layer(i);
    <do something with theLayer>
}
```

You can write this to a CSV XML or JSON file using the `File.write()` or `File.writeln()` methods of the [File object](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/file-system-access/file-object.html). These can easily be imported into Excel.

Because the version of Javascript that extendscript uses dates back to 1995, it doesn't have native `JSON.stringify()` or `XML.write()` methods, so to create JSON or XML you will need Javascript implementations like [this one for XML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-writer) and [this one for JSON](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-json). If you search for core JS polyfill for these functions there are dozens around.